# What happens to previous "staged but not commited" changes?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and just started learning from this site: https://dev.to/unseenwizzard/learn-git-concepts-not-commands-4gjc

My doubt is in this part of the document:

> Have a look at Alice.txt.
> It actually contains some text, but Bob.txt doesn't, so lets change that and put Hi!! I'm Bob. I'm new here. in there.

To summarize, we make a change to Bob.txt with this sentence:- **Hi!! I'm Bob. I'm new here.**
The we *staged* this change but did not *commit* it.
Later on, we went ahead and made another change to the same sentence by removing the extra ! after Hi.

So now the sentence looks like this:- **Hi! I'm Bob. I'm new here.**
Now we *staged* and *committed* this new change.

My doubt is: Is the previous modification to Bob.txt (with the two !!) lost from the staging area?
I ran `git status` but it doesn't mention the previous change. Can I go back and commit the change with the two "!!" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902367/1256452) and [Romain Valeri's addition to that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902551/1256452) are both correct, but might be hard to visualize or understand in various ways.  Here's a way to understand it that might be at least *somewhat* intuitive.

When you're working with a commit in Git, there are up to *three* copies of each file.  Once you know that a commit contains a full snapshot of *every* file, in a read-only (and Git-only, compressed, and de-duplicated) format, you will see why it's necessary to have *two* copies:

```
Git's read-only copy in HEAD        your working tree copy
----------------------------        ----------------------
file1.ext                           file1.ext
file2.ext                           file2.ext
readme.md                           readme.md
```

Even if the contents of `file1.ext` in the *commit* match the content of `file1.ext` in your working tree—your working tree being where you get to see and work on/with the files that Git extracted *from* the commit—the Git copy is in some special, weird, compressed, and read-only format.  Only Git itself can even read this file, and nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite it.<sup>1</sup>  Your working tree contains ordinary everyday files, that everyone can read and write in the ordinary way, so Git really does have to copy it out, every time you check out the commit.

This same principle holds for other version control systems too: in Mercurial, or SVN, or CVS or ClearCase or whatever, you'll often find multiple copies of files (the precise details depend greatly on the VCS).  What's particularly weird about Git, though, is that instead of just *two* copies of each file, Git provides *three:*

```
HEAD (r/o)    staging area    working tree
----------    ------------    ------------
file1.ext     file1.ext       file1.ext
file2.ext     file2.ext       file2.ext
readme.md     readme.md       readme.md
```

The `HEAD` copy is *in a commit and cannot be changed*, so that's that.  The working tree copy is yours to play with as you wish.  The weird thing is this extra copy sitting *between* the HEAD and working-tree versions.

You can't *see* this extra version, at least not easily.<sup>2</sup>  But it's there.  Why?  Well, one answer to that is: "for no reason"—after all, those *other* version control systems don't do this.<sup>3</sup>  But Git does do it, and Git has a reason other than just "to be different".  In particular, the existence of this "staging area" copy allows you to use `git add -p` to *partially add* a file.  There's a whole set of these partial operations (`git reset -p`, `git checkout -p`, etc.), and I personally am not a huge fan of these, but they do exist, and are often used as justification for the staging area's existence.

The data stored *in* the staging area are secretly<sup>4</sup> in the same read-only, compressed, and de-duplicated *form* that Git uses inside commits.  What this does for Git itself is make `git commit` go *very fast* (compared to all those other VCSes, anyway).  When you run `git commit`, the copies of files that are in the staging area are *ready to be committed*.  There's almost no extra work required.<sup>5</sup>  When you run `git checkout`, Git pre-fills the index/staging-area—these are two terms for the same thing, in Git—with all the files *from* the commit you checked out.  As you run `git add`, Git:

- compresses and hashes the working tree file's content;
- checks to see if that's a duplicate; and
- if it's a duplicate, re-uses the old one, otherwise saves the new one

so that the file is ready to go and Git can just update its index entry / staging copy with the new-or-reused internal hash ID.<sup>6</sup>  That means that the index/staging-area is now ready to be committed.

If we put this together, we see the following:

- full-commit-checkout (or `git switch`): fills in the index / staging-area *and* your working tree:

  ```
  HEAD         staging      working tree
  ----         ----------   -------------
  file1.ext -> file1.ext -> file1.ext
  file2.ext -> file2.ext -> file2.ext
  readme.md -> readme.md -> readme.md
  ```
- `git add`: copies from working tree to index / staging-area.  Let's say we just `git add file2.ext`:

  ```
  HEAD         staging      working tree
  ----         ----------   -------------
  file1.ext    file1.ext    file1.ext
  file2.ext    file2.ext <- file2.ext
  readme.md    readme.md    readme.md
  ```

Now various other operations start to make sense too:

- `git rm --cached`: removes the index copy, leaving everything else untouched.  Let's say we `git rm --cached file2.ext`:

  ```
  HEAD         staging      working tree
  ----         ----------   -------------
  file1.ext    file1.ext    file1.ext
  file2.ext                 file2.ext
  readme.md    readme.md    readme.md
  ```
- `git reset`, in one of its modes: restores the staged copy (only) from the HEAD copy, with `git reset -- file2.ext` for instance:

  ```
  HEAD         staging      working tree
  ----         ----------   -------------
  file1.ext    file1.ext    file1.ext
  file2.ext -> file2.ext    file2.ext
  readme.md    readme.md    readme.md
  ```
- `git rm` without `--cached`: removes *both* index *and* working tree copies:

  ```
  HEAD         staging      working tree
  ----         ----------   -------------
  file1.ext    file1.ext    file1.ext
  file2.ext
  readme.md    readme.md    readme.md
  ```
- `git restore`: restores staging, working-tree, or both, depending on flags; let's say we now run `git restore -SW file2.ext` to restore both:

  ```
  HEAD         staging      working tree
  ----         ----------   -------------
  file1.ext    file1.ext    file1.ext
  file2.ext -> file2.ext -> file2.ext
  readme.md    readme.md    readme.md
  ```

The `git checkout` command has modes that emulate two of the things that `git restore` can do: it can either copy from staging to working tree, or from `HEAD` to *both* staging *and* working-tree.<sup>7</sup>  This is kind of dangerous since these operations overwrite the working tree copy even if you never saved it anywhere.  That makes using `git switch` instead of `git checkout` "safer", since you won't get this destructive mode of operation by accident.<sup>8</sup>

Hence, the short answer (too late) is that your second `git add` overwrote the staging copy that your *first* `git add` wrote, throwing away that earlier staging copy.  It's now very hard to get back.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, as long as the file is stored as what Git calls a *loose object*, it's not that hard to read: open the underlying object with any zlib decompression program and decompress it, then discard the header that Git added.  But just finding the object alone is a pain in the keister, and then it could be the opposite of "loose", which is not "tight" but rather *packed*, and then you're really in trouble.

Overwriting the file is physically possible, but because the object's *name* is a cryptographic checksum of the object's *data*, overwriting the file simply damages the data to the point where Git will say "this object is corrupt" and refuse to extract it at all.  You'll know that the repository is damaged and that you should find some other clone that is undamaged.

<sup>2</sup>To see it not-easily, run `git ls-files --stage`; be aware that this dumps out of *lot* of output in a big repository.

<sup>3</sup>Mercurial, for instance, literally doesn't, but does have a hidden thing called the "dirstate" that does *some* of what Git's index does.  The user-oriented difference between Mercurial's dirstate and Git's index, though, is that you don't even have to know that the dirstate exists.  Git shoves its index / staging-area in your face now and then: *Look! I have this extra copy! Isn't it cool? Look, see!* and you really have to be aware of it.

<sup>4</sup>Using `git ls-files --stage` exposes this "secret", so it's not really all *that* secret.  But you don't need to *know* this unless you start using `git ls-files --stage` yourself, and/or couple that with use of `git update-index`.

<sup>5</sup>The one bit of extra work required is that Git has to run the internal equivalent of [`git write-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree).  This saves the file's *names and modes*.  The *data*—the file's *content*—are already "pre-saved", as Romain Valeri noted.

<sup>6</sup>Exercise for the reader: what if you `git add` some content and then *never commit it*, e.g., by overwriting it with new content?  There's an internal Git object that never seems to get used here.  Look at [the `git gc` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) to see what eventually happens.

<sup>7</sup>The `git restore` command has the ability to copy from `HEAD` to working-tree, skipping right over the staging copy, if you like; `git checkout` *can't* do this.  Whether you ever *want* to do this, I don't know: that will be up to you.  But if you decide that you *do* want to do this, remember that `git restore` is *more* capable than this other mode of `git checkout`.

<sup>8</sup>The "destructive mode by accident" thing no longer happens in Git 2.23 and later, which now notes that your `git checkout zorg` request was ambiguous.  Here's where it *does* happen in older versions of Git:

- Suppose you have a *branch* named `origin/zorg`.
- Suppose you also have a *file* named `zorg`, and you've run `git checkout develop` and gotten the `develop`-branch-tip copy of the file.
- Suppose now that you spent the last hour working on your evil plan to fire cab drivers.
- Now you take a coffee break (and carefully *don't* choke on a cherry).  When you come back you think: *Wait, I wanted to be on the `zorg` branch.*  So you run `git checkout zorg`.

You don't *have* a `zorg` branch, but you do have an `origin/zorg`, and you were expecting Git to create a new branch `zorg` from `origin/zorg` and switch to it, if that was safe, or give you an error reminding you to stash or commit your files.  But instead, Git says: *oh, you want me to erase your last hour's work on the file `zorg`* and hence extracts the staging copy of file `zorg` to your working tree.

Had you used `git switch zorg`, Git would have known that you meant to create a *new branch*, and would have tried that safely.  But instead, Git destroyed your work.  Bummer!  Just don't go kill a bunch of people (or even Mangalores) to vent your frustration, OK?

Comment: I only get from all that "Don't kill a bunch of people" ;) Good advice, as always. I also like `git switch` cannot detach HEAD by mistake, while `git checkout` can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309

Answer (score 3):

> Is the previous modification to Bob.txt (with the two !!) lost from the staging area?

Yes: the staging area is to prepare the next commit.
If you change the same file and add again, you modify that staging area, and the next commit will have no idea of your initial state.

> Can I go back and commit the change with the two "!!" ?

Not with Git alone.
If you have an IDE with a [local history feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) of its own, then said IDE could help.

Answer (score 3):

Let's also add that when you stage changes, git internally creates the corresponding trees and blobs in the database, even if they're not yet referenced in any commit.

So `git fsck` should find your "staged but not committed" changes as dangling blobs, which you can inspect with `git cat-file -p <hash>`

So they're *lost from the staging area*, yes, but not *completely unrecoverable.*